SageMath: error trying to find the normal subgroups of a given group
I am new to SageMath and am currently exploring how to find all the normal subgroups of a specific group G. Here's a brief description of G:
Consider the ring R = Z/3Z × Z/3Z, where Z/3Z denotes the field with 3 elements. We define SL(4, R) as the special linear group of 4 × 4 matrices with entries from R.
The group G is a subgroup of SL(4, R), generated by the following matrices:
| (1,1)  (1,0)  (0,0)  (0,0) |   
| (0,0)  (1,1)  (0,0)  (0,0) |   
| (0,0)  (0,0)  (1,1)  (0,1) |  
| (0,0)  (0,0)  (0,0)  (1,1) |,  


| (1,1)  (0,1)  (0,0)  (0,0) |  
| (0,0)  (1,1)  (0,0)  (0,0) |  
| (0,0)  (0,0)  (1,1)  (1,0) |  
| (0,0)  (0,0)  (0,0)  (1,1) |,  


| (1,1)  (0,0)  (0,0)  (0,0) | 
| (0,0)  (1,1)  (1,1)  (0,0) |
| (0,0)  (0,0)  (1,1)  (0,0) |
| (0,0)  (0,0)  (0,0)  (1,1) |,


| (1,1)  (0,0)  (0,0)  (0,0) |  
| (1,0)  (1,1)  (0,0)  (0,0) |  
| (0,0)  (0,0)  (1,1)  (0,0) |  
| (0,0)  (0,0)  (0,1)  (1,1) |,  


| (1,1)  (0,0)  (0,0)  (0,0) |
| (0,1)  (1,1)  (0,0)  (0,0) |
| (0,0)  (0,0)  (1,1)  (0,0) |
| (0,0)  (0,0)  (1,0)  (1,1) |,


| (1,1)  (0,0)  (0,0)  (0,0) |  
| (0,0)  (1,1)  (0,0)  (0,0) |  
| (0,0)  (1,1)  (1,1)  (0,0) |  
| (0,0)  (0,0)  (0,0)  (1,1) |  

I attempted to write SageMath code to find the normal subgroups of G but encountered errors. Here's the code I used:
# Define the finite field Z/3Z
Z3 = Integers(3)    

# Define the ring R as a Cartesian product of Z/3Z and Z/3Z
R = Z3.cartesian_product(Z3)    

# Define the matrices over R
matrices = [    
    matrix(R, [  
        [(1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],    
        [(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0)],    
        [(0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)],    
        [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1)]    
    ]),    
    matrix(R, [    
        [(1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0)],    
        [(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0)],    
        [(0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)],    
        [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1)]    
    ]),    
    matrix(R, [  
        [(1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],  
        [(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1), (0, 0)],  
        [(0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0)],  
        [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1)]  
    ])  
]  

# Include their transposes
matrices += [m.transpose() for m in matrices]

# Generate G as the group generated by these matrices
G = MatrixGroup(matrices)

# Find the normal subgroups of G
normal_subgroups = G.normal_subgroups()

# Display the normal subgroups
normal_subgroups

Expected Outcome: I expected the code to list all the normal subgroups of the group G.
Actual Outcome: I encountered the following error message:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /home/sc_serv/sage/src/sage/structure/category_object.pyx:847, in sage.structure.category_object.CategoryObject.getattr_from_category()
    846 try:
--> 847     return self._cached_methods[name]
    848 except KeyError:

KeyError: 'normal_subgroups'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 36
     33 G = MatrixGroup(matrices)
     35 # Find the normal subgroups of G
---> 36 normal_subgroups = G.normal_subgroups()
     38 # Display the normal subgroups
     39 normal_subgroups

File /home/sc_serv/sage/src/sage/structure/category_object.pyx:841, in sage.structure.category_object.CategoryObject.__getattr__()
    839         AttributeError: 'PrimeNumbers_with_category' object has no attribute 'sadfasdf'...
    840     """
--> 841     return self.getattr_from_category(name)
    842 
    843 cdef getattr_from_category(self, name) noexcept:

File /home/sc_serv/sage/src/sage/structure/category_object.pyx:856, in sage.structure.category_object.CategoryObject.getattr_from_category()
    854     cls = self._category.parent_class
    855 
--> 856 attr = getattr_from_other_class(self, cls, name)
    857 self._cached_methods[name] = attr
    858 return attr

File /home/sc_serv/sage/src/sage/cpython/getattr.pyx:357, in sage.cpython.getattr.getattr_from_other_class()
    355     dummy_error_message.cls = type(self)
    356     dummy_error_message.name = name
--> 357     raise AttributeError(dummy_error_message)
    358 cdef PyObject* attr = instance_getattr(cls, name)
    359 if attr is NULL:

AttributeError: 'FinitelyGeneratedMatrixGroup_generic_with_category' object has no attribute 'normal_subgroups'

Request: Could someone please help me understand why this error occurs and how to fix it? Specifically, I would like to know:

Why the normal_subgroups method is not available for the matrix group G.

How to correctly find the normal subgroups of G in SageMath.


Any assistance in debugging this code or providing a correct approach would be greatly appreciated.

Stackoverflow is not the [math.se] site: there is no LaTeX support here. Please [edit] your post to rewrite those parts to something that's easy to read. LaTeX in code blocks as "this is the code I have" is fine, but not sprinkled in description text. It just makes things way harder to read.

I gather from the error message that normal_subgroups isn't a method for the object G. Try dir(G) to see what are the methods that you could call.

Thank you, @Mike, for the suggestion. I have made the changes accordingly.

Thank you, @RobertDodier, for your kind comment. I noted that normal_subgroups isn't a method for the object G. It would be very helpful if anyone could tell me how to calculate the normal subgroups in this situation.

Deep, it seems likely that there aren't enough people working with the group theoretic functions in SageMath to be able to help you here on Stackoverflow; probably you need to look for a forum devoted specifically to SageMath.
